# How to setup spark in aws ecs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ecs

i have a spark multimaster cluster managed by zookeeper and i want to move this multimaster arch to aws ecs, aws EMR is not an option,

**the question is** how does ecs load balance will work, taking in to the account that every component(spark-master,spark-worker,zookeeper,livy) is deployed in a different service ecs .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

it can not be done spark components are connected thru a config file in compile time, so the solution is to use task definition loopback interface which provides an static ip number(127.0.0.1) and hostname(localhost), so e.g worker connecting to master will be **spark://127.0.0.1:7077**